# How to give delay of 2 us to any pulse?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I Have written a VHDL code to generate a pulse of 0.8 us. my input clock is of 50Mhz. Now I want to give a delay of 2 us to this pulse

```
entity singlepulse is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
           P_out : out  STD_LOGIC);
end singlepulse;

architecture Behavioral of singlepulse is
    signal count : Integer range 0 to 1000000000;
begin
    process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if (rst = '1') then
            P_out <= '0';
            count <= 0;

        elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
            count <= count + 1;
            if (count < 40) then
                P_out <= '1';
            else
                p_out <= '0';
            end if;

        elsif (falling_edge(clk)) then
            if (count <= 40) then
                p_out <= '1';
            else
                p_out <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

i want to give 2 us delay to this generated pulse of 0.8 us. but i don't know where to start and how to start. 
pardon me if it seems silly it's my 3rd day in vhdl so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `falling_edge(clk)`?

Comment: If you know how to reset `p_out` after the pulse duration, what keeps you from using the same construct to delay the setting of it?

Comment: because for falling edge of the clock o/p was getting zero

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that such a construction is not synthesizable. What happens if you remove the whole "`elsif (falling_edge(clk))`-branch"?

Comment: Before worrying about delaying by 2us, let's get this code right first. (As already siad, just delete all the code relating to `falling_edge(clk)`.) If you simulate this code, it will output a single pulse of 0.8us and then will crash at a simulation time of 20s, because the integer `count` will go out of range. (Setting a range on an integer like this _does not_ mean that it will wrap round.) If you want to output a 0.8us pulse every 20s, then you need explicit code to set `count` to zero when it reaches 1000000000.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed in comments, you have several problems in your code :

- Remove the falling edge part
- Your counter is not reseted so it will reach his maximum and regenrate a pulse

If you want a pulse 2 us after the reset release, you just have to raise your output when the counter is between 100 and 140 :

```
architecture Behavioral of singlepulse is

    signal count : Integer range 0 to 1000000000;

begin

    process(clk, rst)
    begin

        if (rst = '1') then
            p_out <= '0';
            count <= 0;

        elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then

            if (count < 100) then     -- Wait 2 us
                count <= count + 1;
                p_out <= '0';
            elsif (count < 140) then  -- Pulse of 0.8 us
                count <= count + 1;
                p_out <= '1';
            else                      -- Stop incrementing counter to avoid new pulse
                p_out <= '0';
            end if;

    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Hi @Gautitho  can we do this using FSM generating these pulses together using case statement?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why you speak about several pulses, this code generates only one pulse (unless if the reset is active). Yes of course you can but the code will be more complex to do the same thing.